# icloud drive doesn't appear using UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, icloud, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

In my app I want import .sqlite from iCloud to restore data, but it's not showing iCloud drive everything is managed, iCloud entitlements are already on and from developer account its enable

[ICloud entitlements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjdOO.png)

In my app, I have integrated this code

```
    @IBAction func btnImport(_ sender: Any) {
        //let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
        let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePNG),String(kUTTypeImage)], in: .import)
        importMenu.delegate = self
        importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


extension MoreViewController : UIDocumentMenuDelegate, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    func documentMenu(_ documentMenu: UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        print("url = \(url)")
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

but it shows me only this

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Are you test it on simulator or on really device ?

Comment: on my iphone6 device

Comment: And what happens when you tap on Browse or on the 3 dots? Tapping Browse should display your iCloud Drive.

Comment: yes it display a files screen with nothing